# How do I find out what queries Django-MongoDB is running?

Tags: django, mongodb

Typically in Django I can find out what queries are being run against the database by:

```
from django.db import connections
...
# run some model queries
...
print connections['default'].queries
```

How might I see the same thing using Django-MongoDB?

Comment: I don't know how to do it in Django, but you can checkout http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Viewing+and+Terminating+Current+Operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much digging through the source:

```
from django.db import connections
db_wrapper = connections['default']
print db_wrapper.db_connection.current_op()
```

prints the output found at the link offered by Ren:

```
{ inprog: [ { "opid" : 18 , "op" : "query" , "ns" : "mydb.votes" ,
    "query" : "{ score : 1.0 }" , "inLock" : 1 }
    ]
}
```

Comment: that's unstable API you're using there. probably better go for query logging. http://paste.pocoo.org/show/569242/

Comment: This isn't for logging purposes as much as I wanted to see what the queries looked like. However, I would be curious to see where you found this as an unstable API because I would like to be able to update this answer if/when the API changes. Thanks!

Comment: Well doesn't query logging show you what the queries look like? The `db_connection` name has been changed (to `database` I think) in the upcoming version.

Comment: It does, but not in the Django Shell when I'm just typing things out in the terminal to play around with an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django's built-in login infrastructure to log DB queries.

Comment: I believe the question the OP is asking is how to get the queries in the first place.